# Django with mypy: How to resolve incompatible types error due to redefined field for custom `User` model class that extends "AbstractUser"?

Tags: python, django, mypy, django-stubs

I have an existing Django project which uses a custom `User` model class that extends `AbstractUser`. For various important reasons, we need to redefine the `email` field as follows:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    ...
```

Typing checks via mypy have been recently added. However, when I perform the mypy check, I get the following error:

> error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type
> "EmailField[str | int | Combinable | None, str | None]", base class
> "AbstractUser" defined the type as "EmailField[str | int | Combinable,
> str]")  [assignment]

How can I make it so that mypy allows this type reassignment? I don't wish to just use `# type: ignore` because I wish to use its type protections.

For context, if I do use `# type: ignore`, then I get dozens of instances of the following mypy error instead from all over my codebase:

> error: Cannot determine type of "email"  [has-type]

Here are details of my setup:

```
python version: 3.10.5
django version: 3.2.19
mypy version: 1.6.1
django-stubs[compatible-mypy] version: 4.2.6
django-stubs-ext version: 4.2.5
typing-extensions version: 4.8.0
```

Comment: Note that such a change breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: @PawełRubin Agreed, 100% —in this specific case though, we broke the Liskov principle very intentionally, as it saves a tremendous amount of engineering, and we’re using no other User-like models.

Comment: If your email field fulfills the contract, what about casting it to the type required in the abstract base class? (`email = cast(EmailField[str | int | Combinable, str], models.EmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True))`)

Comment: @erny But user.email needs to be allowed to be None for some objects under our custom User model

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use [type annotations](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/type_inference_and_annotations.html) that are compatible with the `AbstractUser` base class, but also allow `None` values for the `email` field in your custom `User` model.

```py
from typing import Optional
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    email: Optional[models.EmailField] = models.EmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
```

If you explicitly type annotate the `email` field as `Optional[models.EmailField]`, that would indicate that `email` can be of type `models.EmailField` or `None`, which should satisfy the requirements of both Django and mypy.

By using the [`Optional` type annotation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#optional-types-and-the-none-type), you would maintain the integrity of your custom `User` model, but also adhering to mypy's type checking standards. No more "incompatible types" error.

---

> `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "EmailField[Any, Any] | None", base class "AbstractUser" defined the type as "EmailField[str | int | Combinable, str]")  [assignment]`

It means the type definition for your `email` field in the custom `User` model is not fully compatible with the type expected by the `AbstractUser` class. Given that mypy is strict about type consistency, especially when overriding fields in a subclass, you will need to make sure your field definition matches the expected type in `AbstractUser` while also allowing `None`.

Create a type variable that encompasses the types allowed by `AbstractUser` and your additional requirement of `None`.
And use this type variable in the field definition to satisfy both the base class's and your custom requirements.

```py
from typing import Union, TypeVar
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import Combinable

# Define a TypeVar that includes the types from AbstractUser and None
EmailFieldType = TypeVar("EmailFieldType", models.EmailField, None)

class User(AbstractUser):
    email: Union[EmailFieldType, models.EmailField[str | int | Combinable, str]] = models.EmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
```

`EmailFieldType` is now a type variable that allows the `email` field to be either a `models.EmailField` or `None`, aligning with the types specified in `AbstractUser`. The use of `Union` in the field definition should accommodate the specific type requirements from `AbstractUser` as well as your custom model's need to allow `None`.

---

> ```
> error: Type variable "myproject.models.User.EmailFieldType" is unbound`
> ```

Instead of using a `TypeVar`, you could directly use `Union` to specify that the `email` field can be either of the types required by `AbstractUser` or `None`. That would simplify the type definition and should be more straightforward for mypy to interpret.

```py
from typing import Union
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import Combinable

class User(AbstractUser):
    email: Union[models.EmailField, None] = models.EmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
```

`email` field is declared as a union of `models.EmailField` and `None`. That should satisfy the type requirement for `AbstractUser` while also allowing `None` as a value.

---

> Unfortunately the same issue is happening again

Then you would need a more sophisticated type handling or a workaround that aligns with mypy's expectations, without compromising the integrity of your Django model.

Try and create a custom subclass of `models.EmailField` that explicitly handles the nullable scenario in a way that is compatible with both Django and mypy.

```py
from django.db import models

class NullableEmailField(models.EmailField):
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return super().get_prep_value(value) if value is not None else None

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = NullableEmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
```

As a more drastic measure, you can try completely redefining the field and handling the migration carefully. That approach would entail removing the `email` field from your model and then re-adding it with the new specifications. That is more intrusive and requires careful migration handling.

Comment: Unfortunately doing this still results in `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "EmailField[Any, Any] | None", base class "AbstractUser" defined the type as "EmailField[str | int | Combinable, str]")  [assignment]`

Comment: @sunw OK, I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you -- using `EmailFieldType = TypeVar("EmailFieldType", models.EmailField, None)` and `email: Union[EmailFieldType, models.EmailField[str | int | Combinable, str]] = models.EmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)` per your recommendation, I'm now getting this mypy error instead: `error: Type variable "myproject.models.User.EmailFieldType" is unbound`

Comment: I tried the mypy recommendation and added an inheritance to my `User` class: `class User(AbstractUser, Generic[EmailFieldType]):`

This caused an error to appear that was very similar to my original error: `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "EmailFieldType | EmailField[str | int | Combinable, str]")`

Comment: @sunw OK, I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help @VonC -- unfortunately the same issue is happening again.

Comment: @sunw OK, not sure then... maybe a custom subclass of `models.EmailField`? I have edited the answer to include such an alternative.

Comment: The deeper underlying issue is that mypy is checking for whether new custom classes breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle (see thread from my original question post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77544756/django-with-mypy-how-to-resolve-incompatible-types-error-due-to-redefined-field/77562392?noredirect=1#comment136706998_77544756)

Comment: I appreciate the help and attempts -- however, none of these addresses that main point, and therefore mypy continues to produce the error.

Comment: @sunw Would a `email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)  # type: ignore[error-code]` allows you to ignore only the specific LSP-related errors while still benefiting from mypy's type checks elsewhere?

Comment: @sunw Or use explicit casting (`typing.cast`) to inform mypy that you are aware of the type change and are handling it intentionally (`email = cast(models.EmailField, models.EmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True))`).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change the super class from `AbstractUser` to `AbstractBaseUser`. This would allow to to more easily over-write the specific properties you want to change and give you more flexibility in the long run, at the cost of some extra boilerplate.

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
   ...
   email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
   ...
```

Some extra info: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/

Answer (score 1):

One option is to overwrite the django stubs to be compatible with your user model.

Create a stub file (.pyi) for django and override the type for `AbstractUser` in there, [see here](https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/blob/master/django-stubs/contrib/auth/base_user.pyi).